# How to deal with summation with respect to multi-variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, contest-math

I was solving an Olympiad book "Pearson: Pathfinder for Olympiad mathematics"
In that there was a step in a question that involved summation in 3 variables ,since I tackled this type of thing first time i was unable operate with it . therefore i need your help
it was $$\sum_{1\le a\le b \le c \le6}(abc)$$
I have no idea what it mean?
Does it mean abc are operated one by one or anything else?

Comment: It means you should form the set of all triples $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the condition that $1\leq a\leq b\leq c\leq 6$, take the product $abc$ of each triple, and add all those products.

Comment: Try smaller cases. Can you list out all triples such that $ 1 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq 2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $\sum_{1\le a\le b \le c \le6}(abc)$ represents the sum of all possible products of three distinct integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all greater than or equal to $1$ and less than or equal to $6$ while maintaining the condition that $a\le b\le c$.

In other words, the sum adds up all the products $abc$ where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are chosen from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that $a\le b\le c$.

To evaluate the sum, we can simply list out all the possible triples $(a,b,c)$ and calculate their product $abc$, then add up the products. However, this method can be time-consuming, especially if the number of terms is large.

We can rewrite it as:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\le a\le b \le c \le6}(abc) &= \sum_{a=1}^6 \sum_{b=a}^6 \sum_{c=b}^6 abc \\
&= \sum_{a=1}^6 \left\{a \cdot \sum_{b=a}^6 \left(b \cdot \sum_{c=b}^6 c\right)\right\}
\end{align*}
Finally, we can use a lot of algebra to simplify this up.

Comment: @kimchilover $b$ ranges from $a$ to $6$. I don't see it allowing anything but $6\times6\times6$ for $a=6$

Comment: @kimchilover Ah that line. Thanks for pointing it out, forgot to add that the condition needs to be followed.